# SVA concurrent array comparision

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I'm new to systemverilog and SVA and I'm trying to create an assertion for a prbs generator, comparing any given array (`logic [6:0]`) with the same array 127 clock cycles after. The problem is that the operators I found helpful to compare arrays do not allow concurrency and the ones allowing concurrency operate only with bits.

Trying to exemplify what I wanted to do, would be something like this:

```
logic [6:0] seq
assert property (@posedge clock) (seq === #127 seq));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
property DLY;
  logic MEM [6:0];
  ( 1'b1, MEM = seq ) |-> ##127 (seq_OUT == MEM);
endproperty

DLY_CHK : assert property (@(posedge clock) DLY);
```

ought to do the trick. This uses the a *local variable* and `( , )` construct to assign a local variable (`MEM`). This is then checked 127 clock cycles later.

With the `( , )` construct, if the LHS of the comma is true (which in my example it always is), then the RHS of the comma is executed. You might want to change the `1'b1` to some kind of control signal. You can put one of three things on the RHS of the comma:

- an assignment to a local variable
- an increment or decrement of a local variable
- a call to a task, task method, void function, void function method or system task

See sections 16.10 and 16.11 of [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf).